# Run Javascript function as long as condition is true

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

I'm building a PhoneGap app where user press button which then sends data to server. On the success handler I have a new function that asks user some questions with prompt box and then sends them back to server. So I need to make the prompt box appear as long as the condition "status=ok" is true.

I don't know how many times the prompt box has to appear, it can be anything from 1 to 10 times, so I guess I need to make a some sort of loop, but how can I do it?

This is the code I've been using now:

```
function UpdateRecord(update_id) 
{ var id = getUrlVars()["id"]; 
jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", 
url: serviceURL + "update.php", 
data: 'id='+id , 
cache: false, 
success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
        if(data.key[0].status == "ok"){
            var reply = prompt(data.key[0].QUESTION, "");
                    jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST", 
                    url: serviceURL + "question.php", 
                    data: 'id='+id+'&reply='+reply , 
                    cache: false, 
                    success: function(data) {
                        window.location = "page.html" }
             } else {
                  window.location = "page.html" 
             }
}
});
}
```

Comment: Why did you delete the question?? Anyway, do you need to repeat the whole process, or just the part calling "question.php"?

Comment: I need to repeat the part in success handler. So everything from the `if(data.key[0].status == "ok"){` part

Comment: Sorry, on second reading I realized you have to repeat the whole thing anyway, since the only way for you to know if `data.key[0].status` has changed is to send new AJAX request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what your after is moving the response from the AJAX call into a method `AskQuestion` (or whatever you want to call it). This function would prompt and would query if the answer was correct or not and redirect them to another page:

```
function AskQuestion(data)
{
   var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
   console.log(data);
   if(data.key[0].status == "ok") {
      var reply = prompt(data.key[0].QUESTION, "");
      jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",
                    url: serviceURL + "question.php",
                    data: 'id='+id+'&reply='+reply,
                    cache: false,
                    success: AskQuestion});
   } else {
      window.location = "page.html";
   }
}

function UpdateRecord(update_id) 
{
   var id = getUrlVars()["id"];
   jQuery.ajax({ type: "POST",
                 url: serviceURL + "update.php",
                 data: 'id='+id,
                 cache: false,
                 success: AskQuestion});
}
```